# Повторный вызов функции PHP

Tags: php

Почему повторный вызов функции может вызывать ошибку?

```
function getCurrentShowArr($slug) {
    require_once('some_api.php');
    $allShows = SomeApi::get("/catalog/theaters/networks/kinocentr/shows/all-long.phps")['shows']['show'];
    function showId($arr, $sl) {
        $i=0;
        do 
        $arr[$i]['alias'] == $sl ? $res = $arr[$i]['id']: '';
        while(++$i<count($arr));
        return $res;
    };
    $id = showId($allShows, $slug);
    $data = SomeApi::get("/catalog/theaters/networks/kinocentr/shows/{$id}.phps");
    $show = $data['show'];
    return $show;
}

$film1 = getCurrentShowArr('star-wars-7');
$film2 = getCurrentShowArr('terminator');
```

Сообщение об ошибке:

> [06-Jan-2016 16:58:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare showId() (previously declared in home/domen/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php:126) in home/domen/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/themename/functions.php on line 126

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте текст ошибки в тело вопроса

Comment: По любой причине. Уточните какая ошибка и думаю без текста того класса понять это невозможно

Comment: Вангую, проблема в определении (возможно повторном) функции в теле функции :)

Comment: спасибо, я и забыл о том что вообще лог существует))

Comment: Ну вот теперь все по ошибке и понятно)) местная ванга прав :D

Comment: ну а как исправить незадачу не ванганете?)

Comment: а то я совсем не программист

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы определяете функцию `showId` при каждом вызове функции `getCurrentShowArr`.

Решение проблемы тривиально -- вынесите определение `showId` на уровень выше.

Comment: Минусующие, вы хотя бы комментируйте, что не так ;)

Comment: Теперь я хотя бы знаю, зачем `requre.once()` вообще (+1).

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вынести

```
function showId($arr, $sl) {
    $i=0;
    do 
    $arr[$i]['alias'] == $sl ? $res = $arr[$i]['id']: '';
    while(++$i<count($arr));
    return $res;
};
```

перед функцией function getCurrentShowArr($slug) {